# Passing Lambda Expression condition as parameter in the WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, lambda

My ASP.NET MVC application has multiple conditions to fetch the record from the database for different scenarios. In order to implement the same in the WCF with multiple functions for different conditions. I tried to implement the below code,

ASP.NET MVC code:

```
IEnumerable<WCF.UserApplicationDetails> Search_UserApplicationDetails = 
        shareGatewayClient.GetUserApplicationDetailsByCondition(x => (x.FirstName == Name)).ToList();
```

WCF code - basic http binding endpoint:

```
public IEnumerable<UserApplicationDetails> GetUserApplicationDetailsByCondition(Func<UserApplicationDetails, bool>  condition)
{
    DBContext databaseEntities = new DBContext();
    return databaseEntities.UserApplicationDetails.Where(condition).ToList();
}
```

It was working properly in the same application, but in WCF I'm getting this error:

> Type 'System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry' with data contract name 'DelegateSerializationHolder.DelegateEntry:[http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System'](http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System%27) is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Is there any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: "*It was working with WCF*" - please explain... You cant use refs, outs, delegates or anything else of that nature in a WCF call. These are converted to soap contracts (or similar) and sent across the wire.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Apologize for a typo error "It was working fine with the same application". Is there any way to achieve this dynamically?

Comment: DataContractSerializer is not suitable for serialization delegates, DataContractSerializer is used for data.And statically unknown types cannot be serialized directly.